# Best way to protect frontend pages with Json Web token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, web-development-server

I'm working on a website where the user needs to log in to view the content. I'm working with react for the frontend and i'm using node to develop the API. I'm trying to protect my pages with a json web token, this way once the user logs into, the server gives a jwt which the frontend asks for to let the user to continue navigating or otherwise redirecting him to the login.

I know the server needs to verify the token, and i know i can create a middleware and implementing it to my API routes to achieve this. But my question is, if in the page i want to display i don't need to call any API route how can i verify the token?

I mean, should i create a route only to verify the token? or there is better way to do it?
Any suggestion or code example is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use backend for token verification it is easier to manage in long run and safer. For example , if you use hmacsha256 signature ,  you have to leak your private key to client side for token verification. For client side identity verification, i suggest work with server side rendering instead to limit access to the protected part of website.